# Can someone Tell the command to get the location of nodes ? in network simulators

Tags: networking, ns2

I am new in networks I don't know how to work in simulators. I have to write the commands to get the location of nodes in any of the 10 simulators in my project.

Comment: Old INFO : `node-position-and-energy.tar.gz` https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zuo-PZcyAXhcNwN9uaPp1NqguEtTxkRE/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3):

**NS2:**

```
#include <mobilenode.h>
// using class MobileNode
MobileNode *msit_node;
double xpos=ypos=zpos=0.0
msit_node=(MobileNode*)(Node::get_node_by_address(index));
((MobileNode*) msit_node)->getLoc(&xpos,&ypos,&zpos);
```

**NS3:**

```
#include "ns3/mobility-module.h"
//GetPosition()
Vector ns3::MobilityModel::GetPosition(void )const
//Vector pos = position->GetPosition ();
```

**NetSim:**
Open Mobility Project, and in Mobility.c and go to fn_NetSim_Mobility_Run() function. Inside the default case add following codes

```
fprintf(stderr,"\n The position of %s at time %.2lfms is X=%.2lf and Y = %.2lf \n",DEVICE_NAME(pstruEventDetails->nDeviceId),
pstruEventDetails->dEventTime,
DEVICE_POSITION(pstruEventDetails->nDeviceId)->X,
DEVICE_POSITION(pstruEventDetails->nDeviceId)->Y);
_getch();
```

QualNet
node.cpp
NODE-PLACEMENT FILE
NODE-PLACEMENT-FILE ./default.nodes

**OPNET:**
Location can be viewed from GUI node attributes

```
op_id_self()
op_ima_attr_get(nodeid, "name", &nd_attrG[nodeid].name);
op_ima_attr_get(nodeid, "x position", &nd_attrG[nodeid].x);
op_ima_attr_get(nodeid, "y position", &nd_attrG[nodeid].y);
```

Cooja:

```
var x = mote.getInterfaces().getPosition().getXCoordinate();
var y = mote.getInterfaces().getPosition().getYCoordinate()
```

**OMNet++:**
Castalia framework

```
double x_coor = mobilityModule->getLocation().x;
double y_coor = mobilityModule->getLocation().y;
```

**JSim:**

```
public java.awt.Point location
```

Position of node (coordinates of top left)

**GloMoSim:**
Global Mobile Information System Simulation
Position of nodes is present in file: NODE-PLACEMENT-FILE
Format: nodeAddr 0 (x, y, z)